# T-SQL: How to merge two tables with delete and insert when matched and only insert when not matched?

Tags: sql-server, merge

Here is an example statement to explain what I mean:

```
DECLARE @sourceTable table(ID int, tmstmp datetime, data varchar(max))
DECLARE @targetTable table(ID int, tmstmp datetime, data varchar(max))

INSERT INTO
    @sourceTable
VALUES
     (1, '2015-07-23T01:01:00', 'Testdata6')
    ,(1, '2015-07-23T02:02:00', 'Testdata7')
    ,(2, '2015-07-23T03:03:00', 'Testdata8')
    ,(2, '2015-07-23T04:04:00', 'Testdata9')

INSERT INTO
    @targetTable
VALUES
     (2, '2015-07-23T00:01:00', 'Testdata1')
    ,(2, '2015-07-23T00:02:00', 'Testdata2')
    ,(2, '2015-07-23T00:03:00', 'Testdata3')
    ,(3, '2015-07-23T00:04:00', 'Testdata4')
    ,(3, '2015-07-23T00:05:00', 'Testdata5')

MERGE INTO
    @targetTable T
USING
    @sourceTable S
ON
    S.ID = T.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    DELETE
    -- also want to INSERT newer ID 2 source records here after delete
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ID, tmstmp, data)
    VALUES (S.ID, S.tmstmp, S.data)
;
```

When I make a select...

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    @targetTable
```

...I get the following table:

```
ID  tmstmp                  data
3   2015-07-23 00:04:00.000 Testdata4
3   2015-07-23 00:05:00.000 Testdata5
1   2015-07-23 01:01:00.000 Testdata6
1   2015-07-23 02:02:00.000 Testdata7
```

But I want to get the following table instead:

```
ID  tmstmp                  data
3   2015-07-23 00:04:00.000 Testdata4
3   2015-07-23 00:05:00.000 Testdata5
1   2015-07-23 01:01:00.000 Testdata6
1   2015-07-23 02:02:00.000 Testdata7
2   2015-07-23 03:03:00.000 Testdata8
2   2015-07-23 04:04:00.000 Testdata9
```

How to realize this in one statement, because I use an extensive CTE for the source table.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: how about switching from a CTE to storing the results in a temporary table with meaningful indexing? no option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add some extra rows to the "source" table to take care of clearing out the existing rows, then let all of the current rows fall into the `NOT MATCHED` clause, which is the only one allowed to perform `INSERT` operations:

```
;With Clears as (
  SELECT *,0 as Rem from @sourceTable
  union all
  select distinct ID,'1900-01-01','',1 from @sourceTable
)
MERGE INTO
    @targetTable T
USING
    Clears S
ON
    S.ID = T.ID and s.Rem = 1
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED and Rem = 0 THEN
    INSERT (ID, tmstmp, data)
    VALUES (S.ID, S.tmstmp, S.data)
;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/308)

The basic rule with trying to achieve multiple operations within a `MERGE` statement is you need at least one source row for each action you want to take. It's then a challenge to formulate the `ON` clause and the various additional conditions after the `WHEN` clauses such that each operation applies when you want it to.

E.g. without the extra `and Rem = 0` added to `WHEN NOT MATCHED` above, the extra row we added into `Clears` to remove any rows with `ID` of `1` would instead end up creating an extra row, since there aren't any `ID` `1` rows in the target table.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a simple `DELETE`-`INSERT` work here?

```
DELETE t FROM @targetTable t
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM @sourceTable
    WHERE ID = t.ID
)

INSERT INTO @targetTable(ID, tmstmp, data)
    SELECT ID, tmstmp, data
    FROM @sourceTable s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM @targetTable
        WHERE ID = s.ID
    )
```

You may want to keep the two statements under one transaction.

*EDIT: I just realized you wanted a single statement. But I'll leave it here as an alternate solution.*